# Can't find any custom themes with Gnome Tweak tool

Tags: gnome, themes, customization, icon-themes, tweak

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv7ab.png)I have installed the gnome tweak tool in order to customize my Gnome. I have downloaded some themes and extracted the files from the tar.xz to ~/.themes and I also tried extracting them to /usr/share/themes. Both methods did not work and my Tweak tool only lists the preinstalled themes but not the ones I have downloaded.
I also tried using other themes but that also did not work same error.

[Picture with the file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjZY4.png)
[user themes being on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv7ab.png)

Comment: So these are GTK themes, not gnome-shell themes, is that correct?

Comment: Please , check your screenshot again because both images are the same!

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you downloaded theme from gnome-look.org

I try now this theme.
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1429633/

1. download above zip archive then extract by unzip then `mv` to `/usr/share/themes`
2. reopen Tweaks if you already launched.

[image]